# Unknown symbols allover in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, format

[image]

I want to change the settings so that i should get rid of these symbols..

So how can i do that in eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rightclick -> preferences -> uncheck 'show whitespace characters' -> ok

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is "Show Whitespace Characters". If you cannot find it in the toolbar or menu, the simplest way to disable it is:

press -3
enter "Show Whitespace Characters"
select the command from the list with a double click or hitting